# Name for this adaptive weight updating rule?

Tags: algorithm, math, machine-learning, signal-processing, data-mining

I have the following adaptive weight updating rule. 
The intuition is when recent samples are normal, gradually decrease the weight. When an abnormal occurred, increase the weight by a constant number.

Is there a name for it?

```
w = 0.5
alpha = 0.9
beta = 0.2

for sample in samples:
  if is_normal(sample):
     w *= alpha
  else:
     w += beta
  w = min(w, 1.0)
```

Comment: what does "is_normal" mean in this context, correct classification?

Comment: I've seen this being used as "adaptive learning rate".

Comment: Almost like a pheromone update of a minimal ant colony optimization (ACO), the first part would be the evaporation and the 2nd part reinforcement of the current solution by placing pheromones. Although evaporation is usually called rho and the pheromones placed dtheta. alpha and beta are usually the powers to decide how strong the influence of the pheromones and a priori knowledge is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms